# Error: Index not defined thrown in Firebase cURL query, even after updating database rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've taken a look at some of the other questions that are like mine, and they all seem to be having little to no trouble with their database rules and nested queries. As a result, I'm a little confused as to why my query isn't working out.

Just for reference, here's my query: `curl 'https://----.firebaseio.com/flights.json?orderBy="classes/economy/price"&startAt=2'`

Here's what the relevant database structure looks like:

[image: DB Structure]

My rules are:

[image: DB Rules]

This is the error shown:

[image: Error shown]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define indexes at the location where you run the query. Since your query runs on the `flights` node, you'll need an index on `classes/economy/price` there.

So:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "flights": {
      ".indexOn": "classes/economy/price"
    }
  }
}
```